# Does MVC 2.0 model binding work with Ajax requests?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

i'm just sending a normal POST request using Ajax.BeginForm... i output the form elements using the .TextBoxFor and .HiddenFor etc... all as i should... and when it's posted via ajax to my action method, the object in the action method (named "Comment") is not populated with the values!

Am i missing something? here is the relevant part of my code to those who want to see it...

```
<%  Using Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateComment", "Home",
    New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = Model.CommentDivId,
    .HttpMethod = FormMethod.Post})%>
```

and....

```
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(Function(x) x.Comment.CommentID)%>

 <%= Html.TextAreaFor(Function(x) x.Comment.Comment, 8, 40,
                   New With {.style = "overflow: hidden;"})%>

    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Comment.Comment) %>
```

here is the Action Method, which raises the error... the error is a null reference exception when i try to use the object:

```
 Function UpdateComment(ByVal UpCom As Comment) As ActionResult
```

Dim db = New FPicDataContext
  Dim Updatable = (From c In db.Comments Where c.CommentID = UpCom.CommentID).FirstOrDefault
  Updatable.Comment = UpCom.Comment ' THIS IS WHERE THE OBJECT IS NULL ERROR IS RAISED! BASICALLY, ALL THE VALUES IN UPCOM (AS COMMENT) ARE 0 OR NOTHING.
  db.SubmitChanges()

Dim cm = New CommentModel With {.Comment = UpCom, .CommentDivId = "CommentDiv" & UpCom.CommentID.ToString}

Return PartialView("Comment", cm)

End Function

Comment: I would have expected this to work also! ???

Comment: Pleas give use POST action method code and HTML output of your view.

Comment: hello, i've updated the orig post with the requested details :)

Comment: i'm using, as a "hack" right now, both Request("comment.CommentID") and Request("comment.Comment") to get the comment and the commentId, but god it's aweful, i'd really like to do it the way its meant to be done, in the nice and elegant way!! anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem i eventually solved, turns out object name that model is bound to in action argument must be the same name as the object name you used when doing the TextBoxFor BeginForm etc... tested, confirmed, that was it!

so, in other words, `UpCom` had to be named `Comment` instead :).

however, a note of caution, i have not heard about this requirement anywhere, in any documentation or anything!! anyone have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Why would anyone down vote an answer when vie gone to the effort of providing the answer for anyone that might find it useful, I could have just said nothing and left it this way, it doesn't benefit me to provide the answer. I think SO has a lot of programmer snobs who get a kick out of trying to belittle others while trying to look superior to others in an attempt to satisfy their insecurities in other parts of their lives, after 60 questions, I see this all over SO really, overly snobby programmers that are just full of themselves. What does this say about programmers in general? Curious!

Answer (score 1):

Wait I think I see what you're trying to do now and the answer is yes absolutaly.

There are a couple of jQuery plugins you can grab that will allow the posting of forms using Ajax.

I've used this one and it works fine.  [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)
This one might also work for you.  [.submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: hey thank you for this info, however i'll try to use ajax.beginForm first (better compile time checking) to do this, i'm hoping it would work as advertised, otherwise i think i'm missing something if i don't learn how to do it the way it's intended to be done...

Answer (score 1):

@Erx_VB.NExt.Coder I gave you back the point because I stumbled across this looking for something else and eventually hit the same issue, but the wording wasn't the clearest so I wanted to update and try to help.  In my example I iterate through a Findings object via

```
foreach ( var row in Model.Findings )  /* Doesn't Work */
.
.
.
<td> <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => row.Description)%> </td>
```

and my controller:

```
public void Update(ReportFindingViewModel Finding)
```

and print fields out inside a table.  I was getting hits back to the Action whenever I post, but like you said, the object was null:

```
<%: Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "ReportFinding", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" } )%>
```

As you explained, it was all in the name, but what I want to clarify is that it's the name of the lambda expression that you bind to in the fields. When I changed it to:

```
foreach ( var Finding in Model.Findings ) /* Does Work */
.
.
.
<td> <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => Finding.Description)%> </td>
```

the ModelBinding auto-magically figured it all out.  I'm completely new to using the included ms ajax functionality and pretty new to mvc altogether, but this helped.  Thanks!

Comment: @senseilhitokiri thank you very much for your elaboration, Im glad this was useful and have up voted you so people can see your answer for additional clarification :). Also, if I remember the problem correctly, I don't think mvc likes it when you use the same names for parent and child object/property such as I used "Comment.Comment" where 1st comment is object and 2nd is string.